# Customize the default word definition of GNU readline library?

Tags: readline

GNU readline considers consecutive alphanums as word, and all others are non-words, like `-option1 -option2` has 4 words (`" -", "option1", " -", "option2"`) which makes it unintuitive when moving the cursor around. Is there a way to customize this word definition like consider all non space chars as word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any Readline variable that might help, and [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-forward_002dword-_0028M_002df_0029) seems to be quite clear what words are for these movements, without mentioning any possibility of changing them:

> `forward-word (M-f)`
>
> Move forward to the end of the next word.  Words are composed of letters and digits.
>
> `backward-word (M-b)`
>
> Move back to the start of the current or previous word.  Words are composed of letters and digits.

However, these other motions might be of help:

> `shell-forward-word (M-C-f)`
>
> Move forward to the end of the next word.  Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.
>
> `shell-backward-word (M-C-b)`
>
> Move back to the start of the current or previous word.  Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.

And [metacharacter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-metacharacter) is defined as:

> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘`|`’, ‘`&`’, ‘`;`’, ‘`(`’, ‘`)`’, ‘`<`’, or ‘`>`’.